# Why can't my contacts see photos I send via SMS?

Tags: sms, samsung-galaxy-s-4

Trying to download SMS programs, tried a few, so to have better customizable color options as the new Samsung Galaxy sucks for that. Everything I have tried, whatsapp, GO SMS Pro, Viber, Hangouts, none of them let me send photos to my contacts unless they have the same SMS program. Why?  My basic SMS on the LG Android had all these basic properties and I never had issues.

Answer (score 1):

Images are not actually sent via SMS, but instead use the MMS protocol. For this to work, you must have your MMS access point configured properly (this *usually* happens automatically):

1. Check with your contractors website for their MMS access point details. If they are not listed on their website, contact them.
2. Go to Settings -> Mobile Networks -> Access Point Names (or APNs on some devices) and add a

   *ProviderName* MMS

where *ProviderName* is the name of your provider, e.g. Verizon.

Set all the values to what you got from Step 1. Some values might be missing, you can probably safely ignore them.